# Convert Long to binary - least signifant bit first

Tags: programming

I have found an Arduino function which converts a 2-bytes-`long`-value to a binary value.

e.g. I call `sendCommand(0x05)` And it gives me an output:

`00000101`

```
void sendCommand(unsigned long command){
  for (unsigned long  mask = 1UL << (7);  mask;  mask >>= 1) {

    if (command & mask) {

    Serial.print( "1" );
    } else {

    Serial.print( "0" );
    }
  }
}
```

my Problem is, that I want to have the Least significant bit first. How do I have to adjust this function to achieve this?

e.g.
`sendCommand(0x05)`
shall give an output:

`10100000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void sendCommand(unsigned long command){
  for (unsigned long  mask = 1UL; mask<256UL;  mask <<= 1) {

    if (command & mask) {

    Serial.print( "1" );
    } else {

    Serial.print( "0" );
    }
  }
}
```

PS a long is actually 4 bytes long. But your code only uses 1 byte of it.